# Cannot connect to SSL enabled Oracle DB using JMeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I am trying to connect SSL enabled Oracle DB using JMeter. Below are the steps I followed.

1. Converted the client side certificate to .JKS format and placed this
   .JKS in JMeter bin folder
2. Set the below values in system.properties
3. javax.net.ssl.keyStore=myCert.jks
4. javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=JKSpassword
5. Copied ojdbc10 jar in JMeter/lib folder

JDBC config as below
[image]

However, I'm getting the below error:

Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: IO Error PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, Authentication lapse 0 ms.)

Appreciate any lead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Error PKIX path building failed` indicates certificate error (i.e. missing certificate in chain, expired, self-signed, etc.), however it's a generic message which doesn't tell what's wrong exactly.

You might want to add [the next line](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) to *system.properties* file:

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

and once you figure out what's wrong you should be able to amend JMeter configuration accordingly. For instance if your Oracle installation uses a custom self-signed certificate which is not known by any CA you will need to import this certificate into truststore and make JMeter aware of this truststore via `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` properties

More information:

- [Difference Between a Java Keystore and a Truststore](https://www.baeldung.com/java-keystore-truststore-difference)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)
- [SSL Wit Oracle JDBC Thin Driver](https://www.oracle.com/docs/tech/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl.pdf)

Comment: I have added the certificate to java trust store and let JMeter aware on the same. Now the error is "Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=aaqdT0JUT9ylE45GE+jU4g==))"

Any idea on what causing the error? The ssl debug just shows that the certificate was found. No information on the error though

Comment: Can you specify the JDBC version and JDK version that you are using? Please check  the blog (https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc-tlsv12-jks-or-oracle-wallets-122-and-lower) for the versions that you should be using.

Comment: Issue fixed by using OJDBC8 and JDK9..Trusting the cert in Java keystore and truststore